# WPF binding to data context

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Why XAML binding succeeds to this in my view model:

```
    private string _testStr = "Test";
    public string TestStr
    {
        get { return _testStr; }
    }
```

But not to this:

```
    public string TestStr = "Test";
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because field is not a valid [binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#binding_sources):

**common language runtime (CLR) objects**

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

**dynamic objects**

> You can bind to available properties and indexers of an object that implements the IDynamicMetaObjectProvider interface. If you can access the member in code, you can bind to it.

**ADO.NET objects**

> You can bind to ADO.NET objects, such as DataTable. The ADO.NET DataView implements the IBindingList interface, which provides change notifications that the binding engine listens for.

**XML objects**

> You can bind to and run XPath queries on an XmlNode, XmlDocument, or XmlElement. A convenient way to access XML data that is the binding source in markup is to use an XmlDataProvider object. You can also bind to an XElement or XDocument, or bind to the results of queries run on objects of these types by using LINQ to XML. A convenient way to use LINQ to XML to access XML data that is the binding source in markup is to use an ObjectDataProvider object.

**DependencyObject objects**

> You can bind to dependency properties of any DependencyObject.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a public property not a variable
The get makes it a public property
The idea is to limit what is exposed to the outside world